# jQuery - how to loop through rows on two similar tables

Tags: jquery

I have two tables generated from an Array in PHP. I then want to display each row of each table in turn. But each table should be independent.
I have managed this in the past by specifyng an ID for each table, and then duplicating the javascript for each table, but figure there must be a more efficient way of doing this, that allows for an undefined numberber of tables.
I can't easily add unique ID's as the data comes from a single array, and the number of elements is unknown up front.

I have the below Javascript, but it is picking all the  from both tables, and looping through them (one table at a time), not each table independently.

I tried:

```
var $rows = $(this).child.('.tabResult tbody tr')
```

But that was wrong. Can someone point me in the right direction please.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="../Generic/JAVASCRIPT/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style>
        table{ border: 3px solid #000000; display:inline-block}
        th{ border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; background-color: #CFCFCF; color: #000000; }
        td{ border-width: 2px; border-color: #000000; border-style: solid; }
        td.lastRow{ background:red; }
        tr.lastRow { border-bottom:10px solid #000000; }
    </style>
    <script>

var m = 0;
function showRows()
{
    var $rows = $('.tabResult tbody tr'); //Get ALL Rows

    $rows.css('display','none'); //Hide ALL Rows

    $rows.eq(m).css('display','table-row'); //Show Row

    if (m == $rows.length-1){m = 0;}else{m++;}; //Increment to Next Row
}

function hideShow(time)
{   
    timer = setInterval('showRows()',time); 
};

$(document).ready(function()
{
    hideShow(3000);
}
)           

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="tabResult"> 
        <thead>  
            <tr> <th>Table1</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr> <td>11001</td> </tr>  
            <tr> <td>11002</td> </tr>  
            <tr> <td>11003</td> </tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <table class="tabResult"> 
        <thead>  
            <tr> <th>Table2</th> </tr> 
        </thead> 
        <tbody>  
            <tr> <td>11001</td> </tr>  
            <tr> <td>11002</td> </tr>  
            <tr> <td>11003</td> </tr>
            <tr> <td>11004</td> </tr>  
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if the tables have a different number of cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BzcjU/3/):

```
function showRows() {
    var $tables = $('table.tabResult');    
    $.each($tables, function (index, table) {
        var $rows = $('tbody tr', $(table)); //Get ALL Rows
        $rows.hide(); //Hide ALL Rows
        $rows.eq(m % $rows.length).show(); //Show Row
    });
    m++;
}
```

The code works for any number of tables and different numbers of rows per table.

Comment: cheers, I'm glad to see I was 'relatively' close. The idea of using MaxRow like that never occurred to me though. Cheers.

Comment: It makes the increment per table - so at a given moment table 1 shows td 1, and table 2 shows td 2, etcetera. I'm running into the same issue here: [http://jsfiddle.net/yub4c/3/]

Comment: I spoke too soon, looking at the Fiddle, it doesn't seem to handle the different number of Rows correctly. e.g. When the first table shows Row 4, the first table Shows a blank Row.

Comment: The first table has only three rows. So when showing the forth row, only a row from the second table is shown.

Comment: I see, that's probably my fault for not explaining properly. Each table should always have one row showing, irrelevant of how many rows are in the other tables.

Comment: It should just go back to the start. Basically each table should be looping independently of the others. e.g. when table2 shows row 4, table 1 would be showing row1.

Comment: I've just checked it with 5 tables of differing lengths and it works like a treat. Cheers for this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through 2 steps:

 - Define number of tables:
var $tables = `$("body").children("table.tabResult");`
- Variable $tables is an array of your similar tables. Therefore, you can loop through each table and get all the rows using "`for`" statement.

This approach will work with different number of cells in each table

Comment: Of course, putting the tables themselves into an Array. It seems so obvious once someone else mentions it. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it: http://jsfiddle.net/yub4c/5/

```
var rows = new Array();
$('table').each(function (i) {
    rows[i] = $(this).find('tr:not(.hdr)'); //Get ALL Rows
    rows[i].hide(); //Hide ALL Rows
    //x = $(this).find('tr:not(.hdr)').length;
    //alert(x);
    rows[i].eq(0).show(); //Show Row
    window.setInterval(function() {
        //alert($rows.filter(':visible').index());
        if (rows[i].filter(':visible').index() >= rows[i].length-1) {
            rows[i].hide();
            rows[i].eq(0).show(); //Show Row
        } else {
            rows[i].filter(':visible').hide().next('tr').show();
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

EDIT:

If you add an extra td to one of the tables, it just continues counting!

Comment: Cheers for that, I've tested it with multiple tables and table lengths, and it works great. I especially like that you left the 'alert' rows in, but commented out. As for a relative newbie like me, it is really helpful to see the thought processes that went into this.